# Making linux "Wait" command wait for ALL child processes

Tags: linux, bash, wait

Wait is not waiting for all child processes to stop. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

titlename=`echo "$@"|sed 's/\..\{3\}$//'`
screen -X title "$titlename"

/usr/lib/process.bash -verbose $@

wait

bash -c "mail.bash $@"
screen -X title "$titlename.Done"
```

I don't have access to **/usr/lib/process.bash**, but it is a script that changes frequently, so I would like to reference it... but in that script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#lots of random stuff
/usr/lib/runall $path $auto $params > /dev/null 2>&1&
```

My problem is that **runall** creates a log file... and **mail.bash** is suppose to mail me that log file, but the wait isn't waiting for **runall** to finish, it seems to only be waiting for **process.bash** to finish.  Is there anyway, without access to **process.bash**, or trying to keep my own up to date version of **process.bash**, to make the wait properly wait for **runall** to finish? (The log file overwrites the previous run, so I can't just check for the presence of the log file, since there is always one there)

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Can you provide us with the relevant parts of `ps -ef` after `wait` has finished? That should show which processes are running and which process is a child of which other process...

Comment: My script and Process.bash end almost instantly.  The only remaining process is runall, which runs under random PID's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(
    . /usr/lib/process.bash -verbose $@
    wait
)
```

Instead of letting the OS start `process.bash`, this creates a subshell, runs all the commands in `process.bash` as if they were entered into our shell script, and waits within that subshell.

There are some caveats to this, but it should work if you're not doing anything unusual.

Comment: Wow... so then runall because a child process of my script?  This worked like a charm (I had to change my script to ksh to match process.bash).  Ctrl+C only stops the wait, instead of runall... Ideally I would just be able to run process.bash just without the one "&", but I can't modify that code, and don't want to keep updating my code everytime process.bash changes.  Thanks.

Comment: To have Ctrl-C kill the background process, use trap and kill: `pid=$!; trap "kill $pid; wait $pid; exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM; wait $pid`

Answer (score 5):

`wait` only waits for direct children; if any children spawn their own children, it won't wait for them.

Comment: Is there anyway around this? If I want it to wait for all children, direct and indirect?

Comment: The only other way is to wait by PID or jobspec.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that because `process.bash` has exited the `runall` process will be orphaned and owned by `init` (PID 1). If you look at the process list `runall` won't have any visible connection to your process any more since the intermediate `process.bash` script exited. There's no way to use `ps --ppid` or anything similar to search for this "grandchild" process once it's orphaned.

You can `wait` on a specific PID. Do you know the PID of the `runall` process? If there's only one such process you could try this, which will wait for all running `runall`s:

```
wait `pidof runall`
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the runall is not a child of original script.

Answer (score 1):

You could recuperate the PID of the process for whom you want to wait

And then pass this PID as an argument to the command Wait